# Polymer (core-splitter): errors when trying to move parallel splitters

Tags: polymer, core-elements

I am trying to use parallel splitters ([the last example of core-splitter](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-splitter)) but these move not smoothly. Even at the [official site](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-splitter) in console I get errors. Is there a way to fix this issue?